# Конвертация xsd схемы в класс

Tags: xml, xsd

Всем привет. Пришлось работать с B2MML схемой данных, которая по сути является частным случаем xsd схемы, разработанная для нужд бизнеса. Данная схема имеет очень разветвлённую структуру зависимостей от других схем (подключение происходит посредством include и import). Суть вопроса состоит в том, что после расширения стандарта кастомными  полями (добавлялись в Extension.xsd стандарта) и попытке сгенерировать класс из схемы B2MML-V0600-ProductionSchedule.xsd используя инструмент xsd.exe, в консоль упала ошибка

**Предупреждение при проверке схемы: Ссылка на необъявленную группу моделей "http://www.mesa.org/xml/B2MML-V0600-AllExtensions:EquipmentAssetMapping". строка 404, позиция 14.**

таких сообщений в консоли порядка >50 на каждую подключённую группу в B2MML-V0600-ProductionSchedule.xsd. 
Ниже этих строк я получил ошибку

**Ошибка: Ошибка при создании классов для схемы 'd:\Work\Schema\B2MML-V0600-ProductionSchedule'.
  - Отсутствует группа Location.**

Складывается ощущение, что не отработал участок кода с импортом

```
<xsd:import     namespace="http://www.mesa.org/xml/B2MML-V0600-AllExtensions" 
            schemaLocation="B2MML-V0600-AllExtensions.xsd"/>
```

похожий вопрос есть по ссылке 
[Схожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421577/xsd-warning-and-error-converting-to-c-sharp-class)

Кто что может посоветовать и навести на мысль, как пофиксить проблему? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ на похожий вопрос по ссылке
[Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903031/the-element-is-missing-trying-to-generate-class-with-element-ref)

Как итог: добавил в строку после названия файла основной схему из которой создавался класс, название файла, импорт которого был прописан в нём. Как понимаю xsd приложение криво работает и импортом других схем (именно с import не unclude)